Duplicated config files
I have an issue with my site duplicating configuration files each time I perform an export.


settings.php contains the following sync directory configuration : $settings['config_sync_directory'] = '../sync';
I confirmed the sync related config inside the container :

matches whats in the host system :
//$settings['config_sync_directory'] = 'sites/default/files/config_V2mCmBDV-Kwf_cRCQOIsJooDEwg6fzOxprqotsPwUyBWhZCkA79cyuCb_qImb8C24QeRnXeEXA/sync';

$settings['config_sync_directory'] = '../sync';

I would appreciate any insight as I've run out of ideas how to resolve this.

How are you exporting config?

If you are using Drush, you should run it in verbose mode. Very bad container-to-host sync could perhaps result in what you are seeing, as could odd volume mounts, I suppose. It's also possible that somehow Drush has a different value for the config sync directory than the site does. You are in the best position to get these answers.

@PatrickKenny drush cex

In addition to the points above by mona lisa, I would 1) avoid using ../ in the path; use a path like what is specified in the drupal.org docs (e.g., settings.edo.php:$settings['config_sync_directory'] = dirname(DRUPAL_ROOT) . '/config/base``), 2) check the details of your server environment 3) try deleting the config directory before running drush cex -vvv`

I'm wondering if you have permissions issues on some of those files, causing Drupal to rename with an appended 2 instead of replacing. I would delete all .yml files from the config directory, and re-export. Then re-export again to test if that solved your issue.
